# Azure, Keystone Authentication of Graph API

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, keystonejs

Hi I am new to Keystone JS.
Is there any way to authenticate Keystone JS Graph API with Azure AD Oauth2?

Kindly help me with an example if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Keystone.js is not designed for Authentication and it is better to use [MSAL.JS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso) instead.

> The [Microsoft Authentication Library for JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso) i.e., MSAL.js
>   enables client-side JavaScript web applications, running in a web
>   browser, to authenticate users using Azure AD for work and school
>   accounts (AAD), Microsoft personal accounts (MSA), and social identity
>   providers

You can find some samples which has implemented using MSAL.js [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples).

Please feel free to ask me if you are still facing any issue with implementation.

Comment: I am actually trying to authenticate the GraphQL api that keystone js provides for me with Azure. Is there any way to do that?

Note I am not trying to use Keystone JS as MSAL substitute.

Comment: Yes, The best way is that you can use MSAL library which helps you to authenticate to your app.